# Spring Data JPA inner join with composite key

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have the following tables, with the specified relationships:

[image]

With the following models:

```
...
@AssociationOverrides({
    @AssociationOverride(name = "primaryKey.userId",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "`userId`")),
    @AssociationOverride(name = "primaryKey.citaId",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "`citaId`")) })
    public class UsuarioCita {


private UsuarioCitaPK primaryKey = new UsuarioCitaPK(); 

...
```

Composite Key:

```
@Embeddable
public class UsuarioCitaPK implements Serializable{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private User userId;
    private Cita citaId;

    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
    public User getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(User userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
    public Cita getCitaId() {
        return citaId;
    }
```

In Cita model:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="primaryKey.citaId", cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private List<UsuarioCita> usuarioCita;
```

How do I write a join query in JPQL between  these two tables? Since UsuarioCita is using a composite key.

Comment: What is "write an INNER JOIN" ? You mean in a query? Just put "INNER JOIN" across the relation

Comment: @NeilStockton I mean write a join query in JPQL.

Comment: The fact that you're using composite keys doesn't change anything to how you create an inner join between two associated entities.

Comment: and where is the difficulty? `SELECT c FROM Cita c INNER JOIN c.usuarioCita u`

Comment: @NeilStockton what if I want to filter using a part of the composite key (useId)